# Android Custom RangeSlider view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I am trying to create this view in the image below
[image]

And this is what I have created now

[image]

I created a class for my custom view and extended [RangeSlider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/RangeSlider), This how I extend the rangeSlider

```
    class CustomSeekbarTest @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : RangeSlider(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

After that I get thumbnails from the provided video then draw them inside onDraw function but it feels like 2 different views above each other

This is my onDraw function:

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    if (mBitmapList != null) {
        canvas.save()
        var x = 0
        for (i in 0 until mBitmapList!!.size()) {
            val bitmap = mBitmapList!![i.toLong()]
            if (bitmap != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x.toFloat(), 0f, null)
                x += bitmap.width
            }
        }
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas)
}
```

I know that I should call  `super.onDraw(canvas)` at the beginning of the function but i called it last thing to show what I got now

What am i doing wrong ? and How to make the first image view ?